# Linq filtering nested collection with keeping the parent entity

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to get clients and their orders with cost > 100, which means I want to access `client.Orders` and fetch only those that have `cost > 100`.

```
var list1 = list.SelectMany(c => c.Orders.Where(x => x.Cost > 100), (c,x)=> c).Distinct();

public class Client
{
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public bool ClubMember { get; set; }

        public List<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}

public  class Order
{
        public int ItemCount { get; set; }
        public int Cost { get; set; }
}
```

This returns all the clients who have A order with cost > 100, I want the orders to be filtered out and skip all the ones that do not match my condition. I tried it in some other ways, but did not succeed :( An explanation on the method would be fantastic to have as well.

Comment: could you share the model? its hard to guess the entire structure out of your description... sorry..

Comment: You might want to rephrase your question to make it a bit clearer what the actual problem is. If I understand it correctly you want to get all clients that have an order > 100 and **only** the orders that are actually > 100. Right now you get all customers with orders > 100 but **all** their orders, correct? (And as Bagus mentioned the correct implementation heavily depends on your model, which is why on StackOverflow you are supposed to include a [mcve]).

Comment: A generic approach would be to select all orders > 100 and then group them by customer.

Comment: Manfred, yes this is what i meant, I also added my model now.

Comment: Is `Orders` a `List<T>`? You have to show the class because you want to filter the orders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you don't want to modify the content of your Client objects, here is my proposal:

```
        var list2 = list.Select(c => new  // 1
        {
            client = c,
            orders = c.Orders.Where(x => x.Cost > 100)
        })
        .Where(a => a.orders.Any())  //2
        .ToList();
```

1- Select a new entity which contains (for every initial client) a reference to the client along with a filtered list of its Orders

2- Keep only objects where there is at least one Order (already filtered)

Comment: and you got my vote for explaining the different steps as requested by the OP

Answer (score 0):

Maybe so:

```
var clientsWithOnlyOneCost100 = clients.Select(c => new
{
    client = c,
    orders = c.Orders.Where(o => o.Cost > 100)
})
    .Where(x => x.orders.Count() == 1);
```

Comment: The updated code only returns the client/orders where only 1 order has a cost > 100

Comment: @vc74, yes, but I just tracked `Orders and have only ones that cost > 100`

Comment: But then you're only keeping the items which have exactly 1 order matching the condition, you won't get the items with more than 1 order matching it

Comment: @vc, at first time question was not clear. I thougth we need get clients who has only one order that cost > 100.